# Using Skype Bot on Skype For Business

Tags: botframework, chatbot, skype, skype-for-business

I made a simple bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and i connected my bot to Skype, it works fine. I want to use my bot on Skype For Business. But i want to know does Rich Skype Message Cards(hero card, carousel card, thumbnail card) work on Skype For Business without any coding. So please help me. Does Skype For Business need different interface implementation ?

Comment: Skype for business does not support cards. Check channel inspector.

Comment: No problem for me no images on skype for business chat. Buttons looks like just url. Do my bots replys(text + links) will render to Skype For Business after connection ?

Comment: Yes they will render as links and text